# What action to be used to move woocommerce qty box below product price - if at all possible?

Tags: woocommerce

The code in the woocommerce single product look like this (Astra theme):

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
        <h1 class="product_title entry-title">Woocommerce Product</h1><p class="price"><del><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span>&nbsp;499</bdi></span></del> <ins><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span>&nbsp;374</bdi></span></ins></p>

<form class="variations_form cart" action="https://www.mydomain.no/product/hoodie/" method="post">
<!-- I WANT TO MOVE IT UP HERE //-->
            <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="pa_color">Color</label></td>
                    <td class="value">
                        <select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_color"></select>                      
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><label for="logo">Size</label></td>
                    <td class="value">
                        <select id="pa_color" class="" name="attribute_pa_size"></select>                           
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap">
            <div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation" style="display: none;"></div><div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
            
<!-- I WANT TO MOVE THIS PART //-->
    
            <div class="quantity buttons_added">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="minus">-</a>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5ff4ee9846565">Woocommerce Product quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" id="quantity_5ff4ee9846565" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Quantity" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
            </div>
            
<!-- EOF -- I WANT TO MOVE THIS PART //-->
    
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">Buy Now</button>

    
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="81">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="81">
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0">
</div>
        </div>
    
    </form>
```

As you can see in my HTML comments, I want to separate the quantity input including the plus and minus buttons from the add-to-cart button, and then move that entire div to the first element of the form.

Is this at all possible using functions.php or jquery, or both - without changing the theme file?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: **_Is this at all possible using functions.php or jquery, or both - without changing the theme file?_** With jQuery yes, but it is 'a dirty coding trick'. Only via functions.php, no, changing/overwriting the template file is the way to go

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that instead.